# ASP NET MVC 3 - How to reset database in code first, with two tables and Database.Setinitializer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My problem lies in the lack of experience in MVC. Basically, I have two tables in DB
-Person
-Offer

For each I have created a model and a controller and a model, so the structure looks like that:

```
public class Offer
{
    public int OfferID { get; set; }
    public string OfferTitle { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class OfferDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Offer model.

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Education { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Person model.

Firstly I created the Person model, that added itself to db without any problems. Then I wanted to add Offer table, and I had to use the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges method. I used it for OfferInitializer and PersonInitializer and then there is the Global.asax.cs file

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<OfferDBContext>(new OfferInitializer());
    Database.SetInitializer<PersonDBContext>(new PersonInitializer());

    //Database.SetInitializer<PersonDBContext>(new PersonInitializer());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

From what I understand, I cant do that simply because I am dropping database 2 times, each time populating only one table at a time. How do I reorganize it all, so that I can populate both or more tables at a time, or the whole database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you should not create individual `DbContext` classes for each table. You should instead put all your `DbSets` in the same `DbContext`. Doing this will simplify things greatly for you.

Secondly, you should look into using `migrations`. You should start using them very early in your project.

You work with code first migrations using the Package Management Console.

```
enable-migrations
```

Does exactly what the name implies. Initializes migrations in your project. This will create a folder inside your project and generate the files needed.

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```

This creates a migration. InitialCreate is actually a string and you can change it to whatever you want. This command will generate the scripts needed to create the database from strach.

```
update-database
```

This command verifies the database and applies the migration (or migrations - there can be multiple) required in order to get the database up-to-date.

This is the initial setup. If you do further changes to your first code first classes, or add more, you will just have to add a new migration and then execute it.

```
add-migration AddedFirstName
update-database
```

It's that simple!

There are some more advanced concepts like seed, rollback, update to specific migration, etc., but what I have typed above covers the basics and the day to day usage of migrations.

I recommend you to read this article which explains everything in much more detail:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application